# Scrolling Object Collection do not render item elements based on standard MRTK button properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I'm making a HoloLens app that is intended to display a list of users from a ser in a Holographic UI, for this I'm using the scrolling object collections, My prefab is based on the one provided in the Examples scenes, but displaying a 3x3 grid that can be scrolled horizontally. The items are a based on the default 32x32 HoloLens 2 button. I have created a new icon set to display a custom icon.

At this moment I'm having these issues:

- The items are not being rendered properly. Once I make a button child of the GridObjectCollection it displays all the icons ignoring the Button Config Helper setup (set to use a Sprite in the Icon style property).
- When I scroll the collection, my custom icon keeps rendering outside the clipping box, it only disappears once the item is deactivated because is fully outside the clipping box:

[image]

This issue happens in the Unity editor and the HoloLens device.

I'm using MRTK 2.6.1 and Unity 2019.4.24f1

TBH I don't know what to do to solve this issue, I made my prefab hierarchy basically by hand putting all values form one project to another.

Comment: I did some tests with the official sample and did not reproduce your issue. Can you provide detailed steps to reproduce these issues? Have you tried the sample in **MRTK/Examples/Demos-ScrollingObjectCollection**? Is there the same issue? Also, it is recommended to update your MRTK and use Unity 2020.3(LTS) for development, please refer to [Choosing a Unity version and XR plugin - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/choosing-unity-version).

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same exact problem. I used the button prefab by the example scene. I modified the button tu use an iconset with one sprite (that I have selected t make it show as the icon) and I had to remove everything but the sprite icon otherwise they would be shown. The result is that everything works as expected but not the icon that will just disppear when more than a half of it is outise the Clipping Bounds.

Edit: I'm using MRTK 2.8.3 with unity 2020.3.48f1.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).